# How is Mystogun able to eat apples through his scarf?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Episode 28 of Fairy Tail, Mystogun is eating two apples. That's normally nothing special (obviously) but he is eating them through his "scarf".

How does he do it? I Googled for it, but the best answer is "It's magic". I can't believe that it is that easy.

Do you know how he is doing this?

Comment: "It's magic" isn't really so hard to believe, is it? Natsu can change his body to flames, Happy is a blue cat who can talk and fly, Erza can summon armor and weapons from an alternate dimension, Gray can make ice out of nowhere, Lucy can summon spirits. How do they do that? "It's magic", of course! We don't seem to have any trouble accepting that, but Mystogun eats apples because "It's magic", and mind gets screwed!

Comment: no one bats an eye when mashima gives fan service, but mystogan eats an apple and people get mad...

Comment: Maybe he just took off his scarf at that time. Porlyusica and Mystogan both being from Edolas and all, she probably knows his true identity anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Mystogan is pretty wary about revealing his face to anyone in any situation. His first appearance was at the beginning of the the arc, where he put all of the guild members to sleep, before he took a mission and left, leaving the guild quite mysteriously. If he goes as far as to do this, its safe to assume that:

1. Either he freezes time so that he can remove the scarf, have a bite and then unfreeze time. (Quite unlikely)
2. He wears a glamour charm that allows a mask like covering over his face which is just an illusion, through which he may be able to eat at will

Comment: Concerning your #2 theory--- if he is paranoid about people seeing his face and he went to the trouble of having an illusion of a mask to cover the times he eats or drinks, he is also likely to actually wear a scarf as all. This would be to hide his face from people using magics that see through illusion. But with an illusion spell of a mask, he would then be able to move the real mask just long enough to take a bite or drink and then put it back.

Comment: this reminds me of one of the early naruto episodes with kakashi and the secret of his mask

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that he used illusions in that case. In his fight with Laxus, he uses illusions to make it appear as if the building dissapear, Laxus is caught and the heaven was opened in half to release a giant monster (chapter 120 pages 3-6). Althought Laxus realised it's an illusion, it's probably mostly because it was too absurd to be true.

But a fellow man, famous for being mysterous, to eat apples through his scarf might not be something as easily taken as an illusion than, say the armageddon of mankind.

So I'd say without actually watched the anime, Mystogun was hungry, physically removed the scarf, but created an illusion of still wearing his scarf meanwhile, thus being able to cover his face and enjoy delicious apples.

Comment: Did Laxus notice it was an Illusion? In the anime, it seemed like he started to panic.

Comment: First he panics in the manga, then he [figures it out](http://r1.goodmanga.net/images/manga/fairy_tail/120/8.jpg).